# UITabBarController not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, iphone-5

I'm using a UITabBarController with UINavigationControllers like this

[image]

I add this to the view using

```
tabctrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 548);
[self.view addSubview:tabctrl.view];
```

The screen looks like

[image]

But I can't switch to other tab(ie, touching on tabctrl's tab has no response)

If I change the frame like

```
tabctrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 488);
```

then the screen looks like,

[image]

Now, I can touch the tab and switch to required viewcontroller. How to solve this issue?

I need to get access to the tabctrl when its frame height is 568.

I'm using xcode 4.6.2 and ios simulator 4inch retina.

Comment: Will you clear it first [self.view addSubview:tabctrl.view]; here what is self.view?

Comment: In self. view, view is a UIViewcontroller

Comment: So where it(UIViewcontroller) is added on window?

Comment: Have you taken your project type as TabBar type app

Comment: And what is the purpose of UIViewcontroller

Comment: Ok I now check my ans in ans section

Comment: In the Uiviewcontroller I have a login screen design, If the user types correct login credentials, then I will add the tabctrl to the view

Comment: that's why I'm using Uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tabbar controller might be behind something else on the bottom of the screen. You can test it with code:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: tabctrl]
```

If this fixes your problem, try to find which view is in front of your tabbar controller

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
 [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:tabctrl];
```

rather than:

```
tabctrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
[self.view addSubview:tabctrl.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your rootViewController's wantsFullScreenLayout property to YES

```
tabbarController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES
```

This should solve your tabbar switching issue on 4-inch screen